# How to bypass runtime flag check in DPDK

Tags: dpdk

> ERROR: This system does not support SSE4_1
>   Please check that RTE_MACHINE is set correctly.

Is there any way to bypass this flag in DPDK?

DPDK version 17.08.1
OS : fedora 20

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to bypass this flag in DPDK?

Sure, the DPDK needs to be compiled without SSE4.1, so it will not require SSE to be present at runtime.

If we do not care about portability, the best way to deal with the issue is to compile DPDK with `RTE_MACHINE="native"`, i.e. using `x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc` config (or similar).

This will use the most CPU capabilities your local host supports, but might somewhat limit the portability to other CPUs.

To make it more portable, set `RTE_MACHINE="snb"` to compile DPDK for SandyBridge CPUs and newer.

The full list of supported machines are listed here:
http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/mk/machine

#### EDIT:

According to [DPDK 17.08 Release Notes](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/rel_notes/release_17_08.html):

> Starting with version 17.08, DPDK requires SSE4.2 to run on x86. Previous versions required SSE3.

That was due to the new vPMD functionality, as described in [the patch discussion.](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/25295/)

Comment: yeah but i have compiled it using x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc

Comment: according to release notes of 17.08.1 "Starting with version 17.08, DPDK requires SSE4.2 to run"

Comment: @PI_ED oh, ok. You can self-answer so other people could learn as well... BTW the requirement was bumped due to vPMD: http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/25295/

Comment: i went through release notes after the question so i mentioned it here don't get carried away

Answer (score 0):

dpdk-stable-XX\mk\machine\native\rte.vars.mk
--ifeq ($(SSE42_SUPPORT),)
++ifneq ($(SSE42_SUPPORT),)

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful